# How to get over 200 reputation points every day

Tags: discussion, reputation

I was watching the top users and saw the honourable [Jon Skeet profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) with his <s>136k+</s> <s>558k+</s> 1M reputation. This man has a lot of quality posts and I respect him a lot. He deserves the reputation he has, like a lot of other people here.

How do you get over 200 reputation points/day, though? Taking a sample of Jon Skeet's profile, we can read that over a course of 54 days he managed to gain 13,076 reputation points.

Now, if we do the maths on that:

**13076 ÷ 54 = 242** reputation points/day.

How can someone have **242** reps/day when the limit is 200?

---

(This question was originally floated by [Daok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13913/daok))

This question has led to a humorous [Chuck-Norris-Facts style question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Comment: I don't know if he's trying or not to go up, but as of now, the average is of 280 reps/day. Impressive.

Answer (score 190):

The limit of 200 is only for upvotes. After hitting the limit you still get reputation for accepted answers (+15), accept**ing** answers (+2), and any bounties you earn.

Comment: If this isn't clear in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130654/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow then it needs to be edited

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't ask questions!

Comment: Not to mention bounties!

Comment: @Hello71 Actually, [he does](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=questions). :P

Comment: Skeets Rule No.3: Even if he posts questions, he does not ask them. He merely posts them for educational purposes, because he knows the answer already.

Comment: @Dynamic you know sjas is right. Take a look at the most upvoted question Jon has. He answered it himself. He probably upvoted it all himself too which is how he gets so many points.

Answer (score 132):

### Revisions

EDIT (April 26th 2013): For some time now (I don't know when) the cap is applied just to votes, so it doesn't matter when in the day you get votes vs acceptance.

**EDIT (9 Feb 2009):** I should have come back to this answer a while ago - the policy was changed back again, so you can get over 200 due to accepted answers.

EDIT (29 December 2008): I've left the text below for historical record, but as of about 29th December 2008 8am UTC, the 200 cap is applied to *all* reputation.

---

**Original Text**

As others have said, the 200 cap doesn't apply to accepted/accepting answers. However, it's worth noting that (as far as I can tell) the 200 cap is an overall cap, not a cap on points given from voting. This makes timing important. Suppose in one day someone has 10 answers accepted and receives 40 upvotes. Two example timelines:

- All the answers are accepted before any of the votes: 150 points for accepted answers, 50 points for votes, and then the rest of the "voting points" are "lost" due to the cap. Total = 200.
- All the votes occur before any answers are accepted: 200 points for the votes (the rest being lost due to the cap again) and then 150 points for the accepted answers. Total = 350.

In other words, answers accepted late in the day (UTC) effectively have a higher value. Anyone accepting one of my answers before I've hit the cap aren't really doing my rep any good (assuming I'll get sufficient upvotes to hit the cap anyway). This shouldn't discourage anyone from accepting answers, however - whether mine or others. Reputation is a fun side-show, but the main event here is obviously sharing knowledge.

Comment: Your last sentence is absolutetly right, and it's all to your honor to not be furious about the question. Thx for the infos.

Comment: Why would I be furious about the question? I didn't catch any hint that anyone thought I'd been cheating.

Comment: Shouldn't you get more rep points for answering a question as to how you have so many rep points?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I figure that by "question" Daok meant the general rep cap issue, so that he praised you for not being bitter about "losing" well-deserved rep due to the 200 cap system; in particular when answers from you get accepted before you hit 200 for the day.

Comment: If we lose 200 points because we give away a bounty, can we earn 400 points in one day by votes?

Comment: @user1271772 Yes.

Comment: @10Repisn'tactiveonMSE I think you're wrong. If you lose 200 due to offering a bounty, the most you can earn back the 200 , but nothing more than that. Your final reputation change for the day will be 0.

Comment: @user1271772 I remember reading somewhere that the contrary happens. Let me look for a link.

Answer (score 7):

I recently read the FAQ and after reading this question I read it again :)

**Now here is your answer**

13076 ÷ 54 = 242 reputation points/day **is normally not possible**.

Now read some text from FAQ:

> A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions. You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, **while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.**

Now for example,

A user have 13076 reputation points, have daily gained 200 reputation points and got his 100 answers accepted and achieved 15 bounties.

**So it's hopefully clear how a user can gain more than 200 reputation points per day.**

Answer (score 2):

Basically, only the upvotes count for the 200 points threshold. So, for example, if you get 10 accepted answers and 18 upvotes in a day your daily reputation will be

```
15 * 10 + 10 * 18 = 330
```

And you would have other 20 points available for other two upvotes (even if you received 15 accepted answers first thing in the morning your allowance would be still 200 points).

Comment: Downvotes count also

Comment: @ColeJohnson Downvotes don't give you reputation, though.