# Does StackOverflow have some sort of deal with Google?

Tags: discussion, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How frequently are new questions indexed by search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/how-frequently-are-new-questions-indexed-by-search-engines)

I've noticed something pretty cool a few times over the past few weeks.  A couple of users have posted error messages with their problems on SO.  Usually, I deal with error messages by Googling the error string enclosed in quotes.

Recently, I've noticed that a link to the StackOverflow question I'm looking at appears near or at the top of the results with the posted time, e.g. "- 1 minute ago".  How does SO get new questions indexed by Google so fast?

Comment: It's all about the PageRank.

Comment: Related also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines

Comment: Wow, do I suck at searching on this site or what?