# Google crawling policy for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How frequently are new questions indexed by search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/how-frequently-are-new-questions-indexed-by-search-engines)

I was just curious about Google's crawling policy for Stack Overflow.  One of my friends posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439612/comparison-of-groovy-and-scala-against-java) on Stack Overflow and I simply searched Google for any possible answers on the web.  The first [result](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=scala+groovy+java+comparison) was the question he posted.   I have seen that it normally takes some time to see results in Google, but this was just within 10 minutes.  Was it just coincidental, or does Google follow a different policy for sites like Stack Overflow?

Comment: Duplicate of [Does StackOverflow have some sort of deal with Google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52986/does-stackoverflow-have-some-sort-of-deal-with-google-closed), which was closed as a dupe of [How frequently are new questions indexed by search engines?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/how-frequently-are-new-questions-indexed-by-search-engines).  Only 70 rep to go before I can vote to close, woohoo!

Answer (score 4):

Google recently announced they changed the way pages were indexed, some pages will be indexed immediatly after they have changed if the author of the site sets it up correctly.  I don't have a link at the moment to support this I am affraid.

I too was suprised at how quick a SO question appeared on google.  I would imagine that Google has a priority list of websites that have good quality regular updates and google would prioritise them over other sites with less regular lower quality content who would have a slower indexing rate, perhaps once monthly as supposed to virtual real time.

I think what we are seeing is network speeds and technology improving worldwide.  Domain propogation used to take several days, last time I tried it it was fairly instant.  I think this is what we are seeing with google.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that google seems to crawl popular forums more often, so I don't think it was coincidence