# New Stack Overflow Questions in Google Search Results

Tags: discussion, google, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow work so well with search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines)
>   [Does StackOverflow have some sort of deal with Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52986/does-stackoverflow-have-some-sort-of-deal-with-google)

I noticed that Google indexes and presents Stack Overflow questions in its search results within **5 minutes** from question creation.

Example:
[image: Google Search Results]

Does Stack Overflow have any specific integration with the Google search engine so the new questions appear in Google search results that quickly?

Bearing in mind that Stack Overflow is such a dynamic website (tens or hundreds of questions created in seconds) I do not believe it is possible to index the website in standard way by Google indexer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Stack Overflow did anything to achieve this. Typically google tends to index news sites, blogs and other frequently updated sites with a greater frequency than the rest of the internet.