# How do Stack Overflow questions appear in Google search results in seconds?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO in stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/seo-in-stackoverflow)

I have noticed that when I ask a question on Stack Overflow and I go into Google and search for the question, it comes up in Google in just a minute or so.

How do they do this? I want the secret!

I am a web developer and I know about most things that you can do for SEO, **but** I have no idea how these questions appear in Google this quickly!

I think it's **amazing**!

Comment: Questions _about_ SO should be asked on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: yes now that you have mentioned it, I want to know too...

Comment: Belongs on meta. But I know that [it is a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36925/how-frequently-are-new-questions-indexed-by-search-engines) there so voting to close as off topic.

Answer (score 7):

Google prioritises certain websites for near continuous checks (Facebook, Twitter etc). Unfortunately the only secret is to have a very large, highly ranked and useful website before Google cares enough to crawl you more often.

Answer (score 3):

Google will crawl sites that have lots of new content more often than those that don't.

Since SO gets new content all the time, google pretty much crawls it constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Its no secret. Google or any other search bots love new content in a website. I think Jeff wrote a blog post about it. Searching for it. Will post if I find it ;-)