# How do Stack Overflow questions get onto Google so fast?

Tags: discussion, google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow work so well with search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines)

To start off I am referencing this old Q: [How does Stack Overflow work so well with search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines)

---

So I just asked this question less than 20 minutes ago: [Move all functions to child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968123/move-all-functions-to-child-window)

How is it already number one **one** when I search for it's title on Google?

How in holy *bleeps* did it get there that fast?

What is behind this? How can I use it to better my sites? Or is this some Stack Exchange secret held only by the demi-gods of the SE?

---

24 minutes for this question to get google.

Comment: The more relevant Google thinks a site is, the more often the bot will come by. Simple as that. I don't think there is any further  magic involved.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98083/how-does-stackoverflow-get-indexed-by-google-in-such-as-fast-manner

Comment: @Brandon thanks.. that is how I got to the related question at the top of my OP.

Comment: Really @Pekka? :-P I said i was referencing the old Q which never got a real answer...

Comment: Well, then possible duplicate of [How does StackOverflow get indexed by Google in such as fast manner?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98083)  :)

Comment: @Pekka no, that was dupe, i am referencing what it was duping, bc that question still does not have an answer from the powers that be.

Comment: But what kind of answer are you expecting? They're doing decent SEO optimization, plus their site is held in high regard by Google. That's probably the biggest part of the recipe. There are bits and pieces of what they do in the Stack Overflow blog and codinghorror.com, but I think most of it boils down to, well, *decent SEO*

Comment: There was a mention about how Google bots' crawl settings are at the max on one of the blogs, can't find it for now

Comment: @Sathya, you mean this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/eeeeek-where-is-my-slow-performance/84701#84701

Comment: Related: [Eeeeek where is my slow performance‽‽‽](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/84701#84701)

Comment: And an old blog post:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-importance-of-sitemaps.html

Comment: @Brandon bingo, that one! Thanks!

Comment: Whoops Brandon, didn't see you already posted the same link. Sorry.