# Stack overflow page is number one on Google in 40 minutes

Tags: discussion, seo

How is this even possible?

I was working on a question and I was googling it to see if there was a duplicate. I found the question as the top hit in Google.

I googled for `can all Java code be decompiled`

This is the post I'm talking about.

[If all the bytecode which compiled from java sources can be decompiled to java sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736563/if-all-the-bytecode-which-compiled-from-java-sources-can-be-decompiled-to-java-s?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Whoa. Just looking at the URL gave me a possible clue to the answer. Is it because the OP shared it on Twitter?

Comment: This happens to me all the time.

Comment: Actually it happen to me a lot of times and not just 40 minutes after. If you google this question, you'll find it immediately.

Comment: All your base are belong to Google.

Comment: google love stackoverflow ...

Comment: See this question: [Eeeeek where is my slow performance‽‽‽](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84701/205516)... Google used to crawl SO 10 times in a second - and this was 2 years back...