# Google two time Index same stack overflow question?

Tags: discussion, google, search-engine

Why does the Google search engine indexes  a Stack Overflow question two times?

Please see this [Google Index](https://www.google.co.in/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=display+pdf+to+html+contents+parallel.&oq=display+pdf+to+html+contents+parallel.&gs_l=hp.3...976.976.0.1118.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.0..1c.1.16.psy-ab.hgDdksGS9a0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bmk&fp=f937b014d7d58ef3&biw=1440&bih=799) in this question **Display of html contents in C# - Stack Overflow** and **c# - Display of html contents in csharp - Stack Overflow**,these two question are same.

Why the same question was two time indexed in google ?

Comment: This is an observed behavior. No need to worry.

Comment: ok! Can i do this in my website ?

Comment: Why the fake edit? This has been answered, right?

Comment: @Arjan . any one does not answer to me. so i put the answer vote for that he. okay thnx for your edit . i will wait for any other answer ...

Comment: [Weird](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/183606/timeline). Anyway, I feel Pekka's answer (and the link in his comment) is the best *guess* we can make about Google's internals. Voting to close as not related to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely because of an [edit that changed the title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16996791/revisions) - and hence, the URL Stack Overflow generates for the post -  in between two Google Bot visits.

It's a Google glitch, probably well known and expected, and will be fixed soon, when Googlebot visits again and sees that the [canonical URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) for the second hit has changed.

> ok! Can i do this in my website ?

There is probably no way to exploit this behaviour on your web site. If you provide the same content under multiple URLs, you will probably be punished by the search engine, instead of being listed twice.

Comment: when Googlebot visits again and sees that the canonical URL for the second hit has changed. 

It's good . But how can this question indexed quickly ?

Comment: @Ramesh see [How does Stack Overflow work so well with search engines?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9726) in short, no one knows for sure. There isn't any one specific technique that they're using; they're just an immensely popular resource.

Comment: @Ramesh, also note that Google knows the initial search index is often outdated quite fast: it refuses to show you its cache for very recent questions. It seems it only shows that cache when the content is a bit more stable.