# Stack Overflow - The Game

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, fun

Stack Overflow is a good **[RPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game)** so far with so-called reputation (which I easily decrypted as being xp). But it can become a great RPG. It needs more emphasis every time you make a level. And there should be a few more levels. For example, split the 100 rep level into two levels.

And there should be titles along with each level: Beginner, Helper, Communist, Nerd, Full Grown Geek, Young Jeff Atwood, Young Edsger Dijkstra, and finally: Q.

Personally I want 16 charisma and 18 intel. And 7 strength as every other geek...

Comment: I put on my robe and wizard hat.

Comment: Ooh, I like to play dress up... - http://www.bash.org/?104383

Comment: I think you mean Jon Skeet, not Q.

Comment: No .. Jon Skeet is the highest level.

Comment: Silence must be new here.

Comment: Why must I be new ? I recognize the Jon Skeet. I just think the Q should follow in the logical order of things.

Comment: No .. Jon Skeet is beyond logic. He supercedes Logic.

Comment: Consult Jon Skeet's answer on this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: "And 7 strength as ever other geek..." Speak for yourself. Some of us are jocks in our spare time.

Comment: -1 this question is just silly. and it's not a question. and the comments are even sillier

Comment: Someone needs to cast Ultima on this question and put it out of its misery. ;)

Comment: Sure, let's have some fun!

Comment: @TylerCarter The only one begin that can really claim to be worthy to be after Q is Pinkie. Now *that* is what I would call "supercedes logic"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although I like the game aspects of it, the more and more you try and make it a game, the more and more people are going to treat it like a game, and that isn't always an ideal situation.

Comment: You could put a Game Interface on it Greasemonkey. That would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There are always people trying to *game* the system.

Why should we encourage this behaviour?

---

Yes the game aspect does promote continued activity, but we don't want it to be just another game on the Internet.