# Why does user Community on Stack Overflow have the new Electorate badge?

Tags: support, electorate-badge, community-user

Stack Overflow user [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) (not a real user, I know) got the new [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate) badge ("Voted on 600 questions and has better than 3:1 answer/question vote ratio.").

What is the reason?

Why does this user even have upvotes (currently 320) and downvotes (currently 19298)?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @Roboto: Unexpected behavior could be an indication of a bug in SOFU. Thus reporting it could lead to higher quality of SOFU.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/what-posts-does-the-community-user-upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be explained by this information from Community's profile:

> Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

That still leaves an explanation for the upvotes.

Comment: He also owns the upvotes?

Comment: up or down is irrelevant; the terms of the badge are "voted".

Comment: but why does he have upvotes at all? (a new question)

Comment: @Isaac - So that if a user is deleted, the votes they placed are still maintained.