# Why does Community User have 45380 upvotes on meta and only 458 on SO?

Tags: support, voting, community-user

I am just curious, why does Community User have **45380** upvotes on meta and only **458** on SO?

Why is there such a big difference (almost 100 times higher)? Here's [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1?tab=stats#tab-top) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1?tab=stats#tab-top).

Comment: for Which: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/what-posts-does-the-community-user-upvote

Comment: The downvotes are also odd meta:874 so:21553

Comment: This question is really, "Why do people vote differently on Meta than they do on SO"

Comment: @random, I have seen that post actually, but I don't think thats because of CW posts. SO have tons of CW posts as you know, 458 votes is too low.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is because a LOT of questions get migrated to meta.

The more migrations.. the more community owned upvotes from accounts that don't exist here.

Comment: I see, and that make sense a LOT, like today is his day.