# No answers visible when question page reloads after editing CW answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro

After editing an answer (someone else answer) to the [Great Programming Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes) question no answers are visible when the question page reloads.

Of course the answers are still there, I just have to reload the page to see them again.  I have been able to reproduce this 3 times in a row on this question (have not tried others), and if I get the "are you human" page the result is the same, no answers visible when the question page reloads.

**EDIT**:

I was able to reproduce the bug on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231951/whats-the-next-thing-on-your-list-to-learn) with 119 answers but not [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805/hello-world-what-did-your-first-ever-computer-program-do) with 82 answers, both on SO. So I thought the number of answers might be a factor.   But here on meta changing the [Jon Skeet Facts questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) with it's 272 answers did *not* reproduce the bug nor did editing an answer to the [April Fools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8790/what-question-would-you-have-asked-as-an-april-fool) question.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't want to edit that question to test, since that will bump it to the front page again. See if you can repro it here on Meta with a large question that got migrated. Take your pick from [the questions with at least 80 answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A80).

UPDATE: I edited one of the SO questions with this "bug" (page 5/5, default sort order) and I can't reproduce:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231951/whats-the-next-thing-on-your-list-to-learn/

After editing an answer on page 5 (same one you edited), refreshed fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this bug many, many times. It might or might not have to do with answers with the same number of votes being shuffled around when one of them is edited (and the edited one ending up on a different page than before).

I can recommend this work-around: sort by "newest" instead of "votes" when editing. This also makes it a lot less confusing as answers with the same number of votes stays in the same position.