# Is there a bot on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, robots, site-usage

[In a recent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894846/printing-bfs-binary-tree-in-level-order-with-specific-formatting/1894862#1894862), user Pascal Cuoq noticed a very strangely written reply by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108207/larson).

While reading some answers from his profile, I can't help to think the same.

What do you guys think? (I linked the profile above)

What's the policy on bots on Stack Overflow (one with two accepted answers)?

**Edit:** If I'm wrong, an apology to that user seems appropriate.

Comment: I hope I'm not accusing anyone wrongly of being a bot ...

Comment: The top 100 users on Stack Overflow, except Jon Skeet are rumored to be bots programmed by him: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9138#9138

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214104/are-there-any-bsd-libraries-that-will-find-the-length-of-an-mp3/1803466#1803466 appears to have been accepted purely so the OP can maintain a 100% accept rate. It's the only answer to the question and makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: Looks like http://niklasro.appspot.com/ (link from LarsOn's profile) is actually some sort of an ELIZA bot.

Comment: There was a link (website) added to his profile (was not there ten minutes ago) which suggests this is indeed a bot.

Comment: Wow, it was _just_ added? I find the implications pretty interesting - it monitors what people say about it? (or the easy assumption is that its creator does)

Comment: @ChrisF The English part is hard to make sense of, but the Python part looks like Python to me, and could possibly be a convoluted way to achieve what the OP asked in that question.

Comment: @Pascal - I stand corrected. I was basing my comment on the English.

Comment: After I've read more of the answers, I became convinced this is not a bot. It may be best to delete this question I think.

Comment: @ChrisF, @Pascal: The OP specified that he wants to know the length of an MP3 file in terms of *time*. A suggestion to get the `HEAD` of an online MP3 file and querying its `content-length` does not seem an appropriate answer to that question: It does not say anything about runtime and does not work in absence of a webserver...

Comment: That's very interesting, the **is there a bot on stackoverflow**.  Tell me more.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have decided that I cannot distinguish between a bot and a human being who is a fan of a few select algorithmicians and uses English unconventionally.

It would be very rude of me to imply that a human being fails the Turing test, so I will be careful to avoid doing this again in the future, and I apologize to LarsOn if ey read this.

Comment: [Python code from the recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39502114/4279) makes sense. If it is a bot; well done—keep up the good work.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. There was an answer bot created by the University of Antwerp which ran on Stack Overflow. It mainly focused on Git questions.

The bot is currently closed.

It had answered lots of questions, with many answers actually valid. It even earned good reputation.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4461216/joey-dorrani) to view the bot's profile or [get more info about the bot in this paper](http://bvasiles.github.io/papers/chi16bot.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

It could be due to [machine translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_translation), like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/). See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/76377/harddisk-life-will-reduce-under-linux-than-windows/76424#76424) on Super User (now deleted). For example, from French or Romanian.

Comment: At first I mis-read that as Romulan.

Comment: Context: *[Romulan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulan)*