# What's the official Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange policy regarding bots?

Tags: discussion, policy, robots

One can build bots to comment and answer questions on Stack Overflow (or on any Stack Exchange site).

Is that allowed? What's the official Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange policy regarding bots?

See also:

- [Has anyone ever tried running an answer bot on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/has-anyone-ever-tried-running-an-answer-bot-on-stack-overflow)
- [Is there a bot on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32791/is-there-a-bot-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: see also: [Present and future of bots on Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261172/present-and-future-of-bots-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Related: [Can a machine be taught to flag comments automatically?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically)   (disclaimer: it's mine)

Answer (score 17):

The policy is:

> If we ask you to stop, stop. Don't knowingly break rules; don't create disruptions.

The first sentence is the most important, if you don't stop we will block you. We try to be as patient as we can be with folks that are trying to make generally helpful things, and we'll help you all we can. Just know that we hold the plug, and we will pull it if we think it's necessary.

Beyond that, have fun.

Answer (score 11):

General policy is *sure, but you're to blame if it goes wrong*.

That means that if you can build a bot that provides *helpful, correct* answers that are in accordance with SE policies, nobody's going to bother you about it. (See also: ["Constructive" by xkcd](https://xkcd.com/810/).)

It also means that if your bot breaks all the rules or posts total nonsense instead of answers, it's going to get suspended (and potentially, your personal account may also be suspended). Creating more accounts to circumvent that is *even more* against the rules, so you also shouldn't do that.