# After reading Jon Skeet Facts , it is only logical to

Tags: discussion

<del>i know i will get flamed for this but i will ask it anyway:</del>

After reading   [the Jon skeet facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) , and since i am stuck with trying to find a property for a .net class that apparently doesn't exist  ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131245/c-webclient-assigning-chunk-size-when-using-asyncuploaddata)) .. :(

I am wondering the following:

Is there a way to raise the <del>Batman</del> TheSkeet Sign for him to come for the rescue?

Is it ethical to ask him to modify the .Net framework to expose a property that doesn't exist, even if it was just for me...

TIA

 

 
 **Edit After Jon skeet's answer:**  

 

 
i guess i should have used some < joke>< /joke> tags to show the none serious parts :)..
Your answer is far more professional than my question! ,**and to avoid any misunderstanding  i hold great respect for all those who respond to my questions and i try every offered solution** , but every now and then when i can't find an exposed .net property my 1st thought would be *" i bet Jon skeet can make it exposed"*  .

Comment: There is actually a "Skeet sign", it is called the C# tag (or eventually .net).

Comment: http://sadtrombone.com

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually, I heard something more [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DH5p5iMEbrE).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need me. You need *anyone* who knows the answer. So ask a question as well as you can, and tag it appropriately. I may well look at it anyway, but more importantly someone else may do so quicker. As the volume of questions has increased (and as my 3G signal on the train is somewhat flaky), I no longer always go through all questions in the morning to see if I missed any interesting C# ones overnight.

If you *do* get really desperate for my input, tweeting at me (@jonskeet) usually works - I'll generally check such questions, but I may not provide an answer if it looks like one of the existing ones is correct, or if I don't know the answer. But just to reiterate, the knowledge of the Stack Overflow userbase as a whole is far, far greater than my knowledge as an individual.

Of course, if you're referring to something from C# in Depth, then that *does* make it somewhat me-specific - and as I run a query for "C# in Depth" every day, mentioning the book somewhere in the post is likely to draw my attention to it.

Comment: Thanks alot for taking your time to answer my -notVerySerious- question, Now we have multiple ways of raising the Skeet sign :) ,i added an edit part after your answer for some clarification .

Comment: @Madi With your several references to these Bat signs, now *I do* imagine Jon Skeet appearing in the back of every C# question, suddenly, then answering and going away on the same silent and sudden way.