# Organizer badge given without retagging

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, badges, edits

I just edited the link in [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) and I got an Organizer badge for it. I didn't retag anything, though. Bug?

Comment: Interesting - the question had been retagged last year, in the revision before yours. Maybe that is counted?

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug around awarding the badge and deletion, it will be fixed in an upcoming overhaul of the badge code next week.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to the fact that when you reach 2000 rep (or 100 for CW on meta), there is no **re-tag** per se, only **edit**, which may count as a re-tag from the perspective of the code.

ie: I don't think the code checks what you edited (body, title, or tags) when you edit a post

Comment: Interesting, if it works both ways, you could potentially earn Strunk & White from 300 retags with more than 2k rep.

Comment: the retag link does not appear for >2k users: 'edit' is the only option available.

Comment: @Ether: Your comment says the same as Downvoter's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same thing happen.  I edited some grammar in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408527/when-can-you-put-c-expert-on-your-cv), which was re-tagged by the edit previous to mine (which occurred some 14 months earlier).  I did not change any tags, but was awarded the "Organizer" badge.  I also had over 2k rep at the time.

It seems like it only checked that I edited the question and that the question was re-tagged.  I wonder if someone can test to see if you can earn other, potentially similar badges like "Cleanup" in this manner.

Comment: With my brief testing, it doesn't look like you can ninja the "Cleanup" badge in this manner.