# Verify famous/celebrity user system

Tags: feature-request, users, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a 'Verified Account' thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58486/is-there-a-verified-account-thing)

As I was bouncing around on Stack Overflow I noticed a comment [posted by a particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen). As exciting as it would be if it really was him, I'm a little weary considering the fact that the actual name for a user can be changed at any time.

It made me realize that with potential celebrities on all of the SE sites, a twitter like verification system would fit in perfectly here.

Comment: His answers certainly read like The Real Raymond Chen(tm).

Comment: Superficially related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16137/are-there-famous-developers-using-stack-overflow