# What happens if two questions are identical after conversion to alphanumeric-and-hyphens-only?

Tags: discussion, title, hyperlinks

...Besides one of them getting marked as a duplicate, of course.

Questions have URLs based on the text of the title, with non-alphanumerics removed, upper-case letters downcased, and spaces converted to hyphens. This is clearly not an injective mapping, so what happens when there's a collision?

Just wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions have URLs based on their ID, the title is just for search engines, hence no collisions.

Try this:

[What happens if two questions are identical after conversion to alphanumeric-and-hyphens-only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48789/omg-waffles-and-unicorns)

[Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/omg-waffles-and-unicorns)

Comment: Oh yeah. Forgot about the ID.