# Terminology: What should we call people who ask questions and people who answer them? Please discuss

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers, original-poster

I'm used to forums, where you talk about posters and OPs.

In SE, what can we call someone who asks a question - an OP, a questioner, something else?

What should we call someone who answers - an answerer?

I often want to refer to one or the other in a comment. I haven't been able to spot what others do. Are they using something like OP or do they just skirt around it?

**Addendum**

I see that my question has been marked as a duplicate.

I'll appeal on the basis that the other question is much more specific.

1. It asks for a straight 'translation' of the term "OP" - that's all. There is no request for a discussion as I have indicated in my tags and now in the title itself.
2. It does not ask about what an 'Answerer' should be called. Although someone does address that point, it doesn't appear in the title and so wouldn't be found by a simple search.
3. Although I say it myself, my question title is *much* clearer (and therefore more easily searchable) than the other.
4. I believe that the other question is completely subsumed by mine. If that question is to stand then perhaps it should be edited so that the title reflects the contents.

Comment: Please note Shog9's answer there. I use "questioner" quite a bit but Shog9 does not like that word because "it sounds weird" so it's not listed there.

Comment: @Dronehinge Asker and answerer, answer ’er and ask ’er, and all the night long it was axe her a dance sir.

Comment: @Dronehinge Who can blame Shog9 for that.  Its [asker and answerer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261137) for me.

Comment: Your "not dupe" arguments are solid, but not valid. Ask yourself this: "What other info could my question here obtain which is not already in or cannot be obtained by the other question"? The answer to that is "nothing". The other question answers everything you asked here, including what to name "users who answer". I don't argue that you are *specifically* wanting to discuss potential names/words for a "user who answers", but I don't think there's much more to be gained.

Comment: people, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I use "questioner" and "answerer", as do many others.
There is also "Question author" "Answer author".

Some people use "OP", but I tend not to unless clearly within context in the conversation, as that is well known for *both* "Original Poster" and "Opening Post".

This being a Q&A and not a forum, and the question must come first, "Opening Post" is always the question.
But "Original Poster" could potentially be an answerer or questioner, as answers and questions can be edited, or wikied, so the person who originally created it might not be the last person to have written to it.

So given the potential confusion between how different people use it, and folks familiar with forums etc, I stray away from OP, personally.

Comment: "questioner" still sounds weird to me. I will accept "inquisitor" however.

Comment: @Shog9 TBH it does sound weird to me, as it's grammatically *icky*, but it's the shortest while being unambiguous. But "the inquisitor" sounds like death to us all if we don't answer

Comment: The opposite of an *asker* is clearly a ***reder***, which per the OED means “An adviser, counsellor”, from the noun *rede* meaning “Counsel or advice given by one person to another.” :)

Comment: Not death, @James - sweet death comes only with an answer. Refusing to answer ensures only eternal agony...

Comment: Would you prefer "Inquirer"/"enquirer"?

Comment: @Shog9 Are you sure "inquisitor" is acceptable and not more than weird? [Meaning of inquisitor: *a person making an inquiry,* ***especially one seen to be excessively harsh*** *or searching.*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=meaning:inquisitor)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right.

Comment: @Firelord A person asking a question is making an enquiry.[What is the proper way to say “queryer”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214204/what-is-the-proper-way-to-say-queryer/214265#214265)

Comment: Don't get me wrong but the answer you mentioned doesn't have any link to an online dictionary/source to back up the suggestion (it doesn't matter how many votes it has). The link I mentioned has several online and reputable dictionaries which tend to agree what I wrote in my last comment. In short, I disagree with you! // Though it is a personal choice so  not a concern for me.

Comment: @Firelord Yeah, trouble is language is open to interpretation from various sources and angles, even without considering context. I actually agreed with you before you posted, in my previous comment ;) I just wasn't being serious because, again, interpretation choices.

Comment: @Firelord some people over here are indeed [inquisitive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/243/inquisitive)

Comment: "**Asker**" is commonly used and sounds more natural than "questioner". Shorter, too.