# What is "OP" referring to for nested citation?

Tags: discussion, terminology

I've already read through this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79804/618369), and I know "OP" stands for Original Poster. Now I would like to know what is "OP" referring to for nested citation?

Assume,

asker A posted a question (question_1) where an article is cited,

and then Answerer B posted an answer to that question

and then asker C posted another question (question_2) where question_1 is cited.

Now, when answerer D use the term "OP" in answer to question_2, what is "OP" referring to?

when answerer B use the term "OP" in answer to question_1, what is "OP" referring to?

Comment: OP would refer to original poster. While typically this would refer to the person who asked the question, *which* question may vary with context. Got an example to pick apart?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What does "pick apart" mean?

Comment: Analyse - who the OP is is *heavily* context based.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Did you read my post carefully?

Comment: @yaojp Did you read the glossary carefully?

Comment: It's not even as simple as that; *OP* can refer to both *original poster* and *original post*. Like any pronoun, there will always be times when it's not clear what the referent is. In those cases, all you can do is try to figure out what makes the most sense or, in a comment, actually ask the person who wrote it.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: In a Stack Exchange context it *always* refers to a person (that is, original poster). But it is a good argument for avoiding abbreviations (and other jargon) as much as possible (and at the expense of forgoing the in-crowd feeling - not really a loss of any significance).

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, that's false. At least at the sites I've been a part of, it's meant *original post* also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP is always the asker of the question itself.

If a question cites another question that makes no difference. It's still the asker of the question being answered we'd call the OP not the asker of any cited questions.

So D would call C the OP in your second example, not A. After all asker C might cite more than one question when he or she asks question_2.

Comment: Fyi, op stands for Open Poster and is widely used in Social Media as well, nowadays