# If my reputation goes down, can I lose privileges?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, privileges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can you lose an ability if your reputation falls below a threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold)
>   [Does loss of reputation cause loss of privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/does-loss-of-reputation-cause-loss-of-privileges)

Heaven forbid, I gave a 'funny' answer, and I got down voted pretty severely.

If I do this, is it possible to lose privileges?

Comment: Also relevant: [Should humorous, clever answers be removed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86819/should-humorous-clever-answers-be-removed), [Is humor allowed in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/is-humor-allowed-in-answers), [Should wrong but funny answers be posted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/should-wrong-but-funny-answers-be-posted), [Should I delete an answer that is funny but no longer applicable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57439/), [How can we be more tolerant of humor?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/), etc.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you lose the privileges again if you fall below the threshold by being downvoted or by posting bounties.

You can just delete your question to regain your reputation, if there are no upvoted answers present.

Answer (score 1):

The privileges are tied to your reputation, so yes, losing rep will result in the respective privileges being not available till yor rep meets the privilege criteria.