# SE question URL to title converter stops after 10

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

Typically if a bare URL for a SE question is pasted into a post, it will automatically use the title of said post and hide the URL, e.g.

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts` =>
[Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

But after 10 in a list this seems to stop working.

- [My wife is stuck in a wall, can I save her?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/my-wife-is-stuck-in-a-wall-can-i-save-her)
- [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)
- [How do you safely pray to your god?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/how-to-pray-safely-to-god)
- [What happened to my face?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13441/what-happened-to-my-face)
- [How can I keep monsters out of my nether regions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions)
- [My children are useless. What should I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18376/my-children-are-useless-what-should-i-do)
- [How do I eat a ring?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10963/how-do-i-eat-a-ring)
- [Why did my dog just eat my cat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/why-did-my-dog-just-eat-my-cat)
- [What race should I genocide?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17030/what-race-should-i-genocide)
- [When should I start drinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/when-should-i-start-drinking)
- [Why is my cat blinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18331/why-is-my-cat-blinking)
- [Why can't I butcher a leopard?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7066/why-cant-i-butcher-a-leopard)
- [Can I kill everybody?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13892/can-i-kill-everybody)
- [A Rhesus Macaque has stolen half my stuff!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/a-rhesus-macaque-has-stolen-half-my-stuff)
- [Can I Pass Out from Excessive Drinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/can-i-pass-out-from-excessive-drinking)

However, they are all converted in the preview.

Comment: Did you just go and find all of the most ridiculous question titles you possibly could for this bug report? I thought those were all going to be jokes...

Comment: I just spent the last 5 minutes reading those questions, completely out of context because I've no idea about any of those games. THey're exceedingly funny (or disturbing) if you don't know they're about video games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, except that the limit on meta sites is now 40, not 10 (so editing your question would now show all questions with titles; you'd have to go above 40 achieve the same). See [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have/108475#108475).

Comment: Why would that possibly be by design?