# Question links stop getting converted to title-based links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, meta, linked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SE question URL to title converter stops after 10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90315/se-question-url-to-title-converter-stops-after-10)

When asking [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108115/143965) I found that meta stackoverflow stops converting question links into title text link questions:

[image]

Comment: This sounds familiar. I think there's a limit on the # of links in one post that get converted.

Comment: Sounds like a one-line code fix then :)

Comment: It used to be [10](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90315/se-question-url-to-title-converter-stops-after-10), so apparently it got bumped up at some point

Comment: And @Michael, at some point [it was 30](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83261/preview-of-automatic-titles-for-raw-links-is-limited-to-30-urls) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: that was preview-only though

Answer (score 3):

This [was not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/108115/14) only happening at the bottom. Even after genesis-φ cleaned up some `<s>` (strikeout) that apparently confused things, some links [are still not auto-linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/108115/19). Removing the `facebook` subdomain [fixes this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/108115/17). Still a bug, I guess.

Also: the preview does not show *any* title when using the `facebook` subdomain.

Comment: Ah, of course, because `api.facebook.stackoverflow.com` doesn't exist.