# Has anyone ever hit the rep cap in a day with no posted questions or answers?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm generally curious if this has ever happened. If it has, or even if it hasn't, I'd like to see any such user rewarded with a badge.

> **[Badge name here]** - Has hit the reputation cap for a day without
>   posting a new question or answer

I don't know enough about the data schema and rules to quickly construct a query on data.stackexchange, but I thought about a query that was something like

```
-- They do it in their sleep
-- Users that have achieved the reputation cap in a day without posting a question or answer
```

Comment: If there is anybody, it's probably [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: I'm sure Jon Skeet has reached that point many of times.

Comment: I thought about that, but that implies there has been a day that Jon Skeet hasn't posted something on SO.

Comment: I have heard that he hits the rep cap before logging in daily, but thats just a rumor.

Comment: @Changeling, it's not a rumor. He had said that himself.

Comment: @yoda bounties don't apply to the rep cap

Comment: The purpose of awarding a badge is to reward some positive behavior. So you suggest rewarding a badge for a ... *non-behavior?*

Comment: Isn't it, rather, bounties contribute to the rep cap but are not restricted by it?

Comment: Don't know if it's been done yet to hit 200 strict, but I've earned over 120 reputation prior to any posts for the day, on account of posting an answer just before the UTC date line. Combining that with the usual accruement of upvotes for a vast enough number of answers, it's certainly feasible that various more prominent users, especially on Stack Overflow, might've pulled it off.

Comment: @squillman No, they do not contribute neither for or against the reputation cap. They affect your chance for the >200 reputation badges, but that's likewise independent of the reputation cap.

Comment: @Grace Huh, can't believe I had that wrong all this time....  Cheers.

Comment: @Robert, see: Tumbleweed. A badge can exist to acknowledge the occasional peculiarity. Granted, *not many* exist.

Comment: But absent the badge, I'm still generally curious about any such resultset, so if anyone would like to craft such a query in their copious free time...

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, of course. For a moment I thought the OP was referring to crossing 200 (a la mortarboard), but upon re-reading I see he wasn't.

Comment: I personally am amazed at how much rep I get off old questions and answers.  I would say that it probably accounts for 50% of my total rep.  Granted, I'm a lot less active than I previously was, meaning I only get about 3 or 4 upvotes a week on new content.  But still, it ain't bad.

Comment: It depends on where you live relative to UTC. I have had questions posted late an night (CET) getting upvotes both sides of UTC midnight. If I had lived further away from UTC zero, not all of them would have been counted. There's some randomness here!

Comment: @Kibbee: Same here. I've posted maybe six times this year but have earned 3k+ rep. See also: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/968/staying-power

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've definitely reached the rep cap for the day before posting anything. It's very rare that I don't post anything on Stack Overflow. But there have been a few times that's happened (when I've been on holiday) yet I've still hit the rep cap.

As an example, according to my user profile it looks like I didn't post anything between [this answer on June 1st 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951984/custom-attribute-changes-in-net-4/2951996#2951996) and [this one on June 7th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987439/can-i-use-the-task-parallel-library-in-a-net-3-5-project/2987473#2987473). However, looking at my [rep report for June 1st to 7th](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=22656&date=20100601%207), I hit the cap every day except the weekend. (I did log in almost every day, I think... but didn't post an answer.)

Just for the record, I think I've said that I believe most weekdays I'd hit the rep cap without posting anything and *very occasionally* I've hit the cap before getting up in the morning - but that certainly doesn't happen every day. Usually when I wake up (at 6am UK time, so either 5 or 6am UTC) I'm at between 50 and 150 for the day.

Comment: Yeah, let's go ahead and add that to the [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts). "Jon Skeet once went 3 weekdays without posting on StackOverflow. He hit the reputation cap all 3 days."