# Skeet-specific edit guards?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've just gone to make a simple code formatting edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654867/concatenating-strings-in-mvc-controller) and been **utterly [Skeeted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9218#9218)** by SO's edit-guarding functionality.

See the screen grab.

Usually I try to stay away from gratuitous Skeet content, as I'm sure the man himself must be sick and tired of reading his own name on every other post. However, on this occasion, I kind of feel as though the site has beaten me over the head with an implementation of one of the [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

**My question:** have the StackExchange devs started implementing [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) as edit rules?!

[image: Skeet-specific edit rules]

Comment: It's possible that I should have titled this question "How best to lose my meta rep", but hey ho.

Comment: [We hate fun here.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: FWIW, I got the sarcasm and thought it was humorous.

Comment: -1 for conspiracy theories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jon Skeet actually edited that post.  I've seen that popup before with other user's names.

You got the message because you and Jon were editing at the same time, and Jon beat you to the "Save Edits" button click.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. :) You didn't detect the sarcasm in my question then? ;)

Comment: I got the scarcasm.  I just figured I would provide an actual reason for the popup :)

Comment: @razlebe, your sarcasm was so over the top that it wouldn't be hard to believe you were just confused.

Comment: On a side note, why does http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6654867/revisions not show anything when expanding #4?

Comment: @pimvdb: 48klocs made the same edits as Cybermate.