# Jon Skeet now #2 in Reputation Leagues!

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

Title speaks for itself. An obvious bug.

[image: what is this madness]

Jokes aside, there's a lot of other users showing up in the list twice at the moment.

P.S. If anyone was wondering, this appears to be the case for every site, not just SO. I considered taking a screenshot of the rankings for Meta instead, but Jon Skeet seemed more important than the guy in the top slot there.

Comment: And here I was thinking I'd read this post and reach for the close link. Well played.

Comment: My title is both completely correct and clearly describes the incorrect results. I can't *begin* imagine how one might think otherwise.

Comment: N.B. -- putting the original (and clearly superior) title back, now that the issue is fixed and we don't need to worry about people overlooking my (perfectly sensible) title in their rush to post dupes (with clearly inferior titles).

Comment: I blame that lot over at CERN: http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2011/jul/22/cern-higgs-boson-god-particle

Comment: [meta-tag:status-rebroken]

Comment: Should we award Jon Skeet the badge for being ranked higher than Jon Skeet?

Comment: Jon Skeet is the only person who has ranked higher than Jon Skeet in the SO all-time rep league #HenceProved

Comment: Is this Art Of Photoshop??

Comment: So the list almost read Skeet Skeet Skeet? God damn.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding of what occurred here. Jon Skeet didn't have a lower reputation than Jon Skeet. Rather, Jon Skeet's reputation is greater than all reputations, including Jon Skeet. It's a common mix up.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

Nice try, Jon.  This should be fixed.

Answer (score 380):

This should be added to Jon Skeet's facts :p

- Jon Skeet was once second in rank, behind Jon Skeet

It will be probably fixed the next time the relevant cron job runs.

Comment: Yes, Jon Skeet now has the unique distinction of being the only person ranked higher on SO than Jon Skeet.

Comment: added to [Jon Skeet facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9182#9182)

Comment: Personally i think we should just "clock" his rep and badge count now, rep to 999,999 and badge counts to 99,999 (the only real question is should the badge count be 6 figures or 5?).

Comment: Jon Skeet has coded in SO that shows him in both 1st and 2nd place :)

Comment: @slugster It looks like 999,999 would have been be unfair :) it's [over 1 million now](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet)