# Reputation league weekly position change bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

(I'm aware that this post sounds like a way of drawing attention to doing well recently. It's really not.)

If you look at the [July 24th - 30th SO league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2011-07-24) I was at #1 (just about... by 6 rep!) That correctly shows the change from the previous week as being +1 for me and -1 for Darin.

But if you look at the [July 31st - August 6th league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2011-07-31) I'm still at #1, but it's *still* showing a change of +1 for me. How can I be +1 after I was already #1 the previous week?

Comment: Maybe you're just that good that you *took first place from yourself*!

Comment: @MarcGravell [True story](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99502)!

Comment: I thought you don't visit SO during weekends!

Comment: @Siva: Me? Who said that?

Comment: Well, you gave the schedule only for weekdays http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep/566#566. Nothing for weekend. So, I thought you are sparing us mere mortals to gain points during weekends. :-)

Comment: @Siva: Duly edited to include my weekend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be the case any more – you're #2 in the [July 24th - 30th league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2011-07-24), not #1 – so it seems that our league caches were out of sync when you viewed them (individual leagues are cached independently).

We've just deployed a fix whereby the window of time during which we serve "stale" league data has been drastically reduced, so hopefully you won't notice such a discrepancy in the future.

Comment: Yeah, that [Darin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) guy is a maniac.

Comment: Hmm... I'd been ahead of Darin in that league (just by 4 points) for a while. Something odd's happened, but I can't say what... (I can't remember whether I had 2672 or whether Darin had 2628 before.)