# Did my parents lie to me?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, reputation-leagues

I just happened to click on the [all-time rep leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/187606#187606). I seem to be there twice.

[image]

Can you tell me more about my twin? Is he the evil twin, a representation of the dark side of the soul that every human being has? Or do I need to talk to my parents about the exact circumstances of my birth?

It seems to happen both when logged in as myself, and when not. Can anybody else reproduce this?

Comment: I see both of you too.

Comment: Yes, I can also see it. Pure evil. I expect this will lead to some sort of clone war.

Comment: BTW, this is not the first time something like this happens: [Jon Skeet now #2 in Reputation Leagues!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99502/jon-skeet-now-2-in-reputation-leagues)

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Mat. You know, I'm not sure whether I want this fixed.

Comment: @xiao yeah, I fear that too! I'm also told my evil twin is very foul-mouthed. Nothing like me.

Comment: +1 for the awesome title. @Pekka: Any thougth about starting a Fight Club?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Pekka cannot talk about that because the first rule of the Fight Club is, "never talk of the Fight Club."

Comment: Upvoting just because of the title.

Comment: You evil twin looks better

Comment: +1, love the title. But technically it *is* a duplicate...

Comment: @Mat: I just noticed the question you linked is marked as [tag:status-completed], which seems odd since the problem is still occurring. I wonder why.

Comment: ... looks fixed from here...?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like a duplicate row sneaked into stackexchange.com's `ReputationHistory` table. While we're not yet totally sure what circumstances led to your 2011-10-21 Stack Overflow reputation being the *only* duplicate row in the entire table, we've added some extra logic to prevent this from happening again. Thanks for the report.

Comment: You know you've made it when staff starting adding code to specifically deal with you.

Comment: I can imagine the `if(userId == 187606){/***/}`...

Answer (score 12):

**Spoiler Alert**: reference to a Terry Pratchett/Discworld book in the spoiler block

> I think [Terry Pratchett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Pratchett) covered this in [*Thief of Time*](http://www.harpercollins.com/features/pratchettBooks/description.aspx?isbn=9780061031328). He's not your twin; he's you, born twice.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense when you think about it. A similar theme occurs in "Night watch" btw

Comment: Hmm.. I haven't read that one for a while, I can't quite place it :)

Comment: Vimes hunts notorious mass murderer, thunderstorm occurs...? A very good one, one of Pratchett's best IMO

Comment: Going to check my bookshelf, think I've got it in hardback

Comment: Is there a Diskworld SE? Should there be one?

Comment: Argh, I was _just_ about to start reading this one!

Comment: @GUIJunkie Both SciFi and Literature have Discworld questions.

Comment: @MatthewRead, just kidding, but what has Terry Pratchett to do with either?

Comment: @GUIJunkie: SciFi's full name is "Science Fiction and Fantasy".

Comment: @mmyers, thanks, I should have known that :-(

Comment: @Popular Demand Ooops. At least I know there's a spoiler markup now :/