# Some users are duplicated in the list of Top Users

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues, top-users

A few minutes ago I went to Stack Exchange to see the [Top Users for Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) and found this:
[image]

Hans and David are displayed twice.

Comment: Maybe they have evil twins...

Comment: I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Have you ever read some of Hans Passant's answers? They really are *that awesome*. (Also, yeah; sadly no repro.)

Comment: This has happened before - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110018/did-my-parents-lie-to-me - can't reproduce either right now though.

Comment: This is likely the result of us unplugging lots of cables yesterday...we'll take a look if the problem persist through Monday when Emmett gets in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce this any more either.

I just gave the code a quick readthrough, but the culprit didn't seem obvious. (As Nick noted, we made some network changes over the weekend, so the underlying problem is likely that certain private APIs that leagues depend on were made unavailable at times.)

We'll keep an eye on it going forward.