# Showing two id of same user in list of Top Users

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Some users are duplicated in the list of Top Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129324/some-users-are-duplicated-in-the-list-of-top-users)

When I was visiting the [reputation rankings](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow) page, I found this:

> [image: Marc Gravell doubled]

How it could be possible?

Comment: Yeah, saw that too this morning. Bug!

Comment: This isn't the first time it's happened. Looking for the dupe...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129324/some-users-are-duplicated-in-the-list-of-top-users

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99502/187824

Comment: There's a lot of dupes this time.

Comment: Yes [one more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110018/187824)