# StackExchange Leagues bug

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [I'm ranked twice in the leagues!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149392/im-ranked-twice-in-the-leagues)

Something weird is on [this page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow)

I see this:

[image: StackExchange Leagues]

Am I that big that I need to occupy 2 places? I know I'm not slim, but it's too much :)

Also checked if I'm not logged in, same effect.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149392/187824) [is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148771/187824) [the](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62145/187824) [universal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68419/187824) [problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110018/187824) [now.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129324/187824)