# Duplicate user in reputation league

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, duplicate-user

So I understand that this has happened in the past: [Jon Skeet now #2 in Reputation Leagues!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99502/jon-skeet-now-2-in-reputation-leagues), but all of the "duplicate" posts are marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) so here is a new bug report:

On the [Aviation Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/275/week/aviation/2014-02-16?sort=totalreputation), I am listed twice:

[image: reputation league with lnafziger in 1st and 2nd]

While that's fun and all, it isn't exactly right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first entry is because you're you (and you're logged in as you), and the second entry is because you're first.

The leaderboard always shows your username/rep/rank on top before showing the rest of the leaderboard.

Comment: Interesting....  It would seem that for whoever is ranked #1 that it should only show it once then.

Comment: The main advantage of this feature is that at least here you can see yourself above Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 4):

You **always** see your own profile at the top, so you can see where you stand in comparison with others.

In this case, since you are at the top, you see your profile twice.