# Bug in the rank change in reputation leagues

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

I just visited the reputation league of Math.SE and noticed a mistake in the rating difference. My rank difference should have been -3 rather than -2. Jack d'Aurizio's rank difference should have been +1 rather than 0. For the other top ten users, the correct rank was displayed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm... [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99502/jon-skeet-now-2-in-reputation-leagues?rq=1) must be doing his thing again

Comment: @UnicornsAreVeryVeryYummy No, the fact that I'm twice at #1 is just because I'm at one and I was logged in so the ranking is shown at the top by default. The bug is in the rank difference. (Not sure if you were completely joking)

Comment: We didn't actually *do* anything, but sure. Have a status-completed tag. :) My money's on caching here since the leagues aren't exactly real time.

Comment: @AnnaLear Jack's rep has increased form 1,447 to 1,487. So that put me to place #2. But caching? This was present for three or four days. I wonder how that could happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been fixed. It is correct now.

Apparently, reputation can still change.

My rep for that week increased to 1,501, back to place #1 now!