# How can a user with high reputation submit a suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

According to this: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), registered users without the edit privilege (2000 rep) can suggest edits to any post or tag wiki.
Users whose reputation is more than 2000, their edits will be accepted without going through the review queue. However, I found some cases where a user with high reputation submitted suggested edits and those edits were later accepted. Is there any exception to the rule or am I missing something.

Here is the link to the suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19289701
The edit was accepted by the owner with no more than 100 reputation but the edit was submitted by a user with very high reputation (I thought that suggested edits were reviewed and accepted by users with high reputation/or those who can access the review queue)

Comment: One possibility: the edit was submitted by a low-rep sock puppet, that was later merged into the high-rep user.

Comment: There was a brief period of time when Jon was using an alternate account and then requested it to be merged. I'm guessing this was suggested by that account. The time stamp here is around that time.

Comment: It's Jon Skeet. Don't ask! He has done a lot of [unexpected things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99502/348196) before.

Comment: Jon suggested 15 edits between March 31st and April 13th, 2018. It was shortly after blogging about behavior of the "community" towards new users. Not a wild guess: he wanted to see for  real how it feels like to be a "new user". :)

Comment: It is not the case for the example, but tag wiki edits are still suggested edits up to 20,000 reputation points (and 2 reputation points are earned for each accepted ones up to 5,000 reputation points, after which it changes to access to the tag wiki *review queue*).

Answer (score 6):

The edit was suggested by a different account, with low reputation, which was later merged into the high rep user account, as confirmed in [this comment by Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351492/how-can-a-user-with-high-reputation-submit-a-suggested-edit#comment1177278_351492):

> There was a brief period of time when Jon was using an alternate account and then requested it to be merged. I'm guessing this was suggested by that account. The time stamp here is around that time

So after the merge, there is no way for ordinary users (or even moderators?) to know what exactly happened when looking at the edit history.