# Is it possible to have badges named after great StackOverflow users?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Since some users have so much reputation and have done so much for helping other on Stack Overflow, how about having badges named after them?

Like

1. Jon Skeet Gold badge

   `for having 50 Gold badges`
2. Jon Skeet silver badge

   `for having 500 silver badges`
3. Jon Skeet bronze badge

   `for having 500 bronze badges`
4. Marc Gravell badge

   `for having more than 300 upvotes on an answer`

Since it will be very difficult for obtaining such a high number of badges, they will be, can we can say, *prestigious*. In a way this will honour the users after whom the badges are named.

Or finally maybe we can have a Stack Overflow "hall of fame" for really great users on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There's too much red tape involved in this, as you'd have to get permission from the user, etc.  Also, the users who only *really* deserve these badges are the people themselves, and they already have that badge in the form of their name.

Comment: `we can have a Stack Overflow "hall of fame" for really great users on Stack Overflow.` [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all). Anything else I could help you with? :P

Comment: Why all of the downvotes?  Where the heck else can PresleyDias ask this question?  Are we going to create an environment where good, enthusiastic and well-intentioned users are afraid to contribute???

Comment: @Matthew, [voting works differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta- Ok, thanks.  I didn't know that, and not sure where to (or if I should) ask ;)!

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt : so we'll run out of badges i think in 5 years or fewer :)

Comment: This actually used to be possible on Meta; [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) was once tagged `[jon-skeet]`, as were several other less popular ones.

Answer (score 1):

I once half-jokingly proposed an "Egregious" badge

```
for earning 200 daily reputation for 30 consecutive days
```

(At tex.sx, one of our top users, [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg), has done just that.)

Comment: So we'd award Jon Skeet with that how many times?

Comment: Let's just say the badge couldn't be earned multiple times. ;-)

Comment: Technically, you should, if you can do it over multiple 30-day windows.  It wouldn't be a *rolling* 30 days.