# May we have the Jon Skeet Facts thread back?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, undelete-request

I did a google search for "Jon Skeet facts" but the meta page which listed them all is gone: [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Google cache still has a copy, but may I ask the Powers That Be to `UPDATE TABLE SET deleted = false` for that question? The answers there are pretty funny and cool additions to geek culture! And soon they will be erased from the internet when google's cache updates!

Pretty please?

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. (The deletion of the meta questions, I mean. Not the requests to reinstate them.)

Comment: Indeed @BoltClock.  Let's delete the Many Memes of Meta while we're at it.

Comment: DELETE THE MANY MEMES QUESTION AND I WILL RAGEQUIT THESE SITES! :-p

Comment: (I'm not sure if people upvoting that comment are supporting my anger at possibly losing the meme question, or are supporting me ragequitting...)

Comment: It's all caps.  People like all caps.

Comment: Thank you, Won't, for making my 10k+ MSO rep slightly less worthless.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize that undeleting questions on meta was a 'thing'. mainly because i am only on meta when i have a complaint, which is generally pretty infrequent!

Comment: was it casperOne again?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn They're both pretty ridiculous

Comment: Also, I am asking this because a friend who works at google asked me "Who is Jon Skeet - he just did a review of some code I submitted." How am I supposed to help her without this knowledge?

Comment: As Jon Skeet himself so eloquently put it: *"The Jon Skeet Facts page isn't really about me. It's about making geek jokes where the exact subject is largely irrelevant."*

Comment: Especially as the question was mentioned on Hanselminutes 302 with Jon Skeet, it seems a shame it's gone now...

Comment: Why are they being deleted anyway? Is SO becoming that desperate to look like the absolute most perfect no-fun site?

Comment: @Won't ran out of memes.

Comment: I can't tell you how many informative questions of mine have been deleted by the powers that be. The long term solution is to topple the powers that be.

Comment: @Evan: I *can* tell you, if you're really interested...

Comment: @Shog9 can you remove the block that stops me from asking questions? Or, do you not yet have enough EXP for that spell?

Comment: @OffBySome While unfathomable, no.

Comment: @Evan: interestingly, there's no explicit toggle for that ban; you just have to have less accumulated down-votes.

Comment: What community decided on that? I have more EXP than a new user and per Jeffery's own words that means I'm more established and respected. I DEMAND JUSTICE.

Comment: I demand a winning lottery ticket, but that ain't happening any time soon.

Comment: We need a SO Museum for stuff like this.

Comment: @Jesse - why?  I think this post is great right where it is.

Comment: @AdamRackis so it has a hallowed place where we can all bask in it's glory.  On second thought a temple would be better.

Comment: Oh dear lord, **now it's happening on Meta, too**. When will the deletion (and consequent whining) cease?!

Comment: @CodyGray calling it whining is unfair. I _said_  "pretty please"

Comment: @Cody - I never knew software developers were capable of being so anti-fun.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Undeleted. There's a very good argument to be made for shedding bits of SO history like so many dead skin cells as we move forward, but that question's *classic comedy gold* - you don't ever **shed your navel**.

When Jon stops answering questions on Stack Overflow, we'll talk about it.

Comment: Was there a reason for deleting my answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123311/155556

Comment: What answer?  I saw a comment masquerading as an answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is relevant to the OPs question. but ooook...

Comment: I am a fervent deletionist, and I support keeping this question *as long as Jon doesn't object*. I support keeping it because it is relevant to Stack Overflow, since Jon Skeet facts are part of the SO culture. It's not really a question with an answers, but the standards for that can be relaxed on meta sites.

Comment: I don't want it deleted - just all the answers locked so it stops getting **pointless** edits from people trying to extract all the jokes from the answers and making them unfunny in the process.

Comment: @amana: Deleted to forestall discussion until I could finish typing up an explanation for *why* it was undeleted. If you honestly want it back, I can undelete it - but it really didn't add much.

Comment: Jon Skeet **did** stop answering questions on Stack Overflow.  Our questions are easily answered by a very small shell script he wrote.

Comment: @Shog9 I would want it back.. As you can see from the quality of some other answers I don't see how mine deters from it. But if you feel it should remain deleted you can. As they say *the ball is in your hands.*

Comment: @amana: **p00f** - it's back. You might consider editing it to add something useful (and/or entertaining...)

Comment: @Shog9 I try. but my comedy doesn't type well haha. I just got back from vaca, so my mind a bit boggled, might have been from this: http://youtu.be/X6fCk8w8VDY :-P

Comment: Hmm.. it's not deleted but Chrome is blocking it saying "Danger: Malware Ahead!" due to content from `www.freeimagehosting.net`. As it's locked I can't edit the bad links away, can you please do that?

Comment: Done, @ShaWizDowArd

Answer (score 17):

[image]

## ***Damn you, Jon Skeet!  You've defeated me for the last time!***

Comment: (:-P **Ha Ha.**)

Comment: Somehow, voting by people who liked the Jon Skeet facts question has caused your Meta rep to go _up_ by 98 points. I HOPE YOU'VE LEARNED YOUR LESSON, YOUNG MAN

Answer (score 7):

### And **p00f**!

**It is back with a vengeance!!**

[image: Secret reason for the continued existence of this question]

Comment: Will's non-answers are so treasured on meta they have the power to bring other non-answers back to life

Comment: @MichaelMrozek :-P