# Where is the constructiveness about the "Jon Skeet Facts" question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I failed to see a valid reason to not flag the [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) question as not constructive (other than I didn't see the flag link, but lets not focus on that part)

I understand that it was once deleted and hopefully [reopened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123307/may-we-have-the-jon-skeet-facts-thread-back) (it really doesn't hurt to have some fun once in a while), but why isn't it closed as not constructive? Is he that powerful that this is not possible?

Comment: *Yes*. He is that Powerful. (Its also probably one of those questions considered historical)

Comment: `I failed to see a valid reason to not flag the Jon Skeet Facts question as not constructive` -- Well, go right ahead then.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you really followed the instructions on the parenthesis: `(other than I didn't see the flag link, but lets not focus on that part)`

Comment: It's locked...does it really need to be closed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, this is Meta.

Secondly, we have mechanisms for protecting historical artifacts... questions that, despite being off-topic (which the Jon Skeet Facts question is not), are nevertheless preserved because they have some quality that merits preservation.

Thirdly... Well, just read [this.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/)

Comment: well, I understand the _preservation_ part, but will locking it would really destroy it?

Comment: Er... No.  I don't think "locking" [means what you think it means.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk)

Comment: `This is Meta` No, this is Patrick.

Comment: @ajax333221: "but will locking it would really destroy it?" Um, it *is* locked. That's why it has that big banner on it that says, "locked by Robert Harvey♦".

Comment: sorry, I meant _closing_

Comment: @ajax333221: Given that no extra answers can be added due to it being locked already, what benefit would closing it have?