# Selecting multiple values when editing posts

Tags: discussion, edits, capitalization, serial-edits

When editing post, is it possible to select multiple text items e.g. "dont" or "i" and replace with a different value (in this case "don't" or "I")?

Comment: so, you want tiny, single-letter fixes even easier than they are now? :-)

Comment: no, to be able to select any identical value, and I don't know what you are talking about, easier than they are now? I have to change them all individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to select multiple text items while editing posts. However you can do this trick. Just copy whole post (from editing window) and paste it in your personal text editor where you can select multiple text items (just for an example MS Word) and replace all selected items then copy that text from your text editor in to post's editing window. This is what I do sometimes when there is too many things to update.

Comment: Excellent suggestion thank you

Comment: @Yve - Obviously it has to be an excellent suggestion because I got it from [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155003/187824) :D