# Follow experts on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page, users, feed

If I want to follow a technology expert, it may be any technology, the how can I know a person and follow him for good answers?

Comment: Subscribe to the person's news feed. Here's yours: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1923055

Comment: Counter-proposal: follow *topics* (a.k.a tags) that you are interested in. If you find good answers (from *anyone*), you learn something new. If you find a question without a good answer, you can *write one* (and learn something in the process).

Comment: You mean the [Chuck Norris of SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow does not have a follow or friend feature through which you can track someone's answers as it leads to unintentional gaming of the system. Well known people like Jon Skeet will get lots of followers very quickly, and hence end up getting a lot more upvotes on their answer.

However, every user gets their own RSS feed. You can find this at the bottom of the user profile. Yours, for example, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1923055). You can subscribe to this use any RSS/Atom feed reader if you want.

Comment: Jon already gets three of four times the number of upvotes he can "use", so that doesn't really matter. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson It was just an example :P Jon is a user most people have heard of, so it is easy to understand. He probably wouldn't notice the extra votes.

Comment: @ragav got some points