# flag number not disappearing

Tags: bug, flags, chat

Browser: Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 on Xubuntu 13.04

I recently experiencing the issue that the flag number is not being removed when I click on it and the popup tells me that there is no flag anymore.

The pop up text and the "show all" are displaying that there are none anymore but the number keeps being displayed on my chat avatar.

A refresh on the page works and the flag disappears.

Comment: How often are you seeing this, roughly?

Comment: I saw this today at least two times in the last 2 or 3 hours.

Comment: Has it started (again) recently?

Comment: I didn't see any flags rising... maybe we should test this directly in chat somehow? I guess it started end of last week, iirc. I am in the [android](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) chat room, if you want to test it...

Comment: For the record, I am seeing it both with Chromium and Firefox (with two distinct accounts) so that's probably not a browser-specific bug.

Comment: Nice to see, that my question is closed as duplicate and the referred question was created 7 days after mine: Seems I managed to have a Jon Skeet fact applied to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9277/138437