# Do most users start on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I understand that SO is the most popular SE site, but what percent of users start there? How often do people come initially to the other SE sites and then perhaps join SO?

Is this a statistic that can be pulled up by site?

The real reason I want to know this is that if I am seeing an opinion of people on Writers let's say 50 people agree and upvote, am I 99% seeing the opinion of 50 programmers who are also sometimes write, and missing out on the general population?

Comment: While I think this is *generally* an interesting question, I'm not sure that it will answer your question. Even if 50% of the site started on SO, that doesn't tell you which of the 50% of the site voted on your question and its answers.

Comment: Yes, they do. Rene wrote a [SEDE query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284133/295232) to check this.

Comment: @Laurel I don't think to answer my question there is a need for a little more math

Comment: You underestimate my Math abilities?

Answer (score -2):

To answer my own question and to go above the duplicate doing some math with the results here is the sites by percentage of attracting new users to SE.

```
1.     Site                               First %       
-----  ---------------------------------  ------------ 
2.     StackOverflow                      78.04983787  
3.     StackOverflow.Ru                   37.05086613  
4.     StackOverflow.Ja                   32.067274    
5.     StackOverflow.Br                   30.22023143  
6.     StackExchange.Mathoverflow         24.67494224  
7.     StackExchange.Expressionengine     24.61021094  
8.     StackExchange.Civicrm              24.52185792  
9.     StackOverflow.Es                   23.95160269  
10.    StackExchange.Tridion              23.76636455  
11.    StackExchange.Math                 22.28402818  
12.    StackExchange.Salesforce           22.09385344  
13.    StackExchange.Gis                  21.93098709  
14.    StackExchange.Drupal               19.4909835   
15.    StackExchange.Mathematica          18.73872248  
16.    StackExchange.Sharepoint           18.59846707  
17.    StackExchange.Ubuntu               18.52466935  
18.    StackExchange.Physics              18.49571464  
19.    StackExchange.Judaism              17.88801203  
20.    StackExchange.Magento              16.74489723  
21.    StackExchange.Tex                  15.39185033  
22.    StackExchange.Chemistry            15.11781837  
23.    StackExchange.Blender              14.57527754  
24.    StackExchange.Hermeneutics         14.53865337  
25.    StackExchange.Stats                14.21048606  
26.    StackExchange.Electronics          13.98349783  
27.    StackExchange.Rus                  13.79111368  
28.    StackExchange.Monero               13.34681496  
29.    StackExchange.Tor                  13.07350765  
30.    StackExchange.Elementaryos         12.86161063  
31.    StackExchange.Wordpress            11.91136502  
32.    StackExchange.Quant                11.51252408  
33.    StackExchange.English              11.35968815  
34.    StackExchange.Rpg                  11.31898971  
35.    StackExchange.Patents              11.22334456  
36.    StackExchange.Bitcoin              11.04972376  
37.    StackExchange.Christianity         11.02199538  
38.    StackExchange.Worldbuilding        10.86464713  
39.    StackExchange.Japanese             10.43329532  
40.    StackExchange.Craftcms             10.42121685  
41.    StackExchange.Graphicdesign        10.32132922  
42.    StackExchange.Sqa                  9.980503899  
43.    StackExchange.Linguistics          9.902504301  
44.    StackExchange.Sound                9.892525647  
45.    StackExchange.Biology              9.73986228   
46.    SuperUser                          9.655973666  
47.    StackExchange.Genealogy            9.519572954  
48.    ServerFault                        9.509192317  
49.    StackExchange.Dsp                  9.382089951  
50.    StackExchange.Scifi                9.348022395  
51.    StackExchange.Ethereum             9.280906837  
52.    StackExchange.Chinese              8.932552954  
53.    StackExchange.Islam                8.826109844  
54.    StackExchange.Aviation             8.806747705  
55.    StackExchange.Academia             8.686336767  
56.    StackExchange.Joomla               8.553459119  
57.    StackExchange.Windowsphone         8.501274033  
58.    StackExchange.Space                8.466780239  
59.    StackExchange.Networkengineering   8.405149484  
60.    StackExchange.Economics            8.361805431  
61.    StackExchange.Android              8.262417199  
62.    StackExchange.Russian              8.190279214  
63.    StackExchange.Esperanto            8.185840708  
64.    StackExchange.Buddhism             8.105700713  
65.    StackExchange.German               8.083962182  
66.    StackExchange.Gaming               8.083037975  
67.    StackExchange.Apple                7.980371658  
68.    StackExchange.Spanish              7.922736945  
69.    StackExchange.Earthscience         7.844408428  
70.    StackExchange.Arduino              7.820492538  
71.    StackExchange.Writers              7.755061923  
72.    StackExchange.Philosophy           7.70302028   
73.    StackExchange.Movies               7.632899987  
74.    StackExchange.Travel               7.59760816   
75.    StackExchange.Ux                   7.477594707  
76.    StackExchange.Anime                7.46834073   
77.    StackExchange.Diy                  7.438525738  
78.    StackExchange.Ell                  7.326787334  
79.    StackExchange.Cstheory             7.179054054  
80.    StackExchange.Sitecore             7.152061856  
81.    StackExchange.Cooking              7.115550623  
82.    StackExchange.Hinduism             7.092391304  
83.    StackExchange.Security             7.085106125  
84.    StackExchange.GameDev              7.069301419  
85.    StackExchange.WebApps              7.007123881  
86.    StackExchange.Raspberrypi          6.998819847  
87.    StackExchange.French               6.899618806  
88.    StackApps                          6.892752204  
89.    StackExchange.Ham                  6.838565022  
90.    StackExchange.Garage               6.837377665  
91.    StackExchange.Astronomy            6.821917808  
92.    StackExchange.Crypto               6.75154321   
93.    StackExchange.Homebrew             6.750861079  
94.    StackExchange.Reverseengineering   6.736944142  
95.    StackExchange.Pm                   6.717000781  
96.    StackExchange.Bricks               6.713344316  
97.    StackExchange.Portuguese           6.671721001  
98.    StackExchange.Unix                 6.66682188   
99.    StackExchange.Italian              6.650943396  
100.   StackExchange.Cogsci               6.638714186  
101.   StackExchange.History              6.593265907  
102.   StackExchange.Bicycles             6.587403599  
103.   StackExchange.Ukrainian            6.542056075  
104.   StackExchange.Photography          6.482692994  
105.   StackExchange.Music                6.389546988  
106.   StackExchange.Puzzling             6.389088299  
107.   StackExchange.Meta                 6.382940229  
108.   StackExchange.Matheducators        6.377295492  
109.   StackExchange.Gardening            6.37025481   
110.   StackExchange.Engineering          6.355932203  
111.   StackExchange.Scicomp              6.350301984  
112.   StackExchange.Dba                  6.333154607  
113.   StackExchange.Moderators           6.309751434  
114.   StackExchange.Robotics             6.293706294  
115.   StackExchange.Expatriates          6.159695817  
116.   StackExchange.Workplace            6.140072609  
117.   StackExchange.Sustainability       6.114718615  
118.   StackExchange.Money                6.098770329  
119.   StackExchange.Pets                 5.919931857  
120.   StackExchange.Health               5.880766118  
121.   StackExchange.Woodworking          5.875227135  
122.   StackExchange.Law                  5.839416058  
123.   StackExchange.Opendata             5.829534466  
124.   StackExchange.Codegolf             5.824472306  
125.   StackExchange.Crafts               5.815602837  
126.   StackExchange.3dprinting           5.788225998  
127.   StackExchange.Parenting            5.693594706  
128.   StackExchange.Latin                5.563093623  
129.   StackExchange.Poker                5.5613851    
130.   StackExchange.Audio                5.537157239  
131.   StackExchange.Webmasters           5.494657651  
132.   StackExchange.Arabic               5.439330544  
133.   StackExchange.Programmers          5.423868866  
134.   StackExchange.Ebooks               5.367734282  
135.   StackExchange.Augur                5.333333333  
136.   StackExchange.Korean               5.305466238  
137.   StackExchange.Politics             5.24399126   
138.   StackExchange.Cs                   5.188410422  
139.   StackExchange.Languagelearning     5.146533238  
140.   StackExchange.Skeptics             5.111063187  
141.   StackExchange.Retrocomputing       5.088666153  
142.   StackExchange.Emacs                4.966352624  
143.   StackExchange.Outdoors             4.956772334  
144.   StackExchange.Chess                4.887398179  
145.   StackExchange.Coffee               4.841858649  
146.   StackExchange.Sports               4.839667458  
147.   StackExchange.Productivity         4.80635125   
148.   StackExchange.Datascience          4.571839986  
149.   StackExchange.Codereview           4.558208955  
150.   StackExchange.Fitness              4.552047306  
151.   StackExchange.Boardgames           4.420823771  
152.   StackExchange.Bioinformatics       4.419889503  
153.   StackExchange.Literature           4.37235543   
154.   StackExchange.Musicfans            4.258443465  
155.   StackExchange.Cseducators          4.222451081  
156.   StackExchange.Interpersonal        4.13552566   
157.   StackExchange.Startups             4.127169316  
158.   StackExchange.Mythology            4.019292605  
159.   StackExchange.Beer                 3.976688378  
160.   StackExchange.Martialarts          3.900414938  
161.   StackExchange.Softwarerecs         3.653415454  
162.   StackExchange.Hsm                  3.589948145  
163.   StackExchange.Freelancing          3.415697674  
164.   StackExchange.Hardwarerecs         3.387533875  
165.   StackExchange.Lifehacks            3.303819215  
166.   StackExchange.Computergraphics     3.15258512   
167.   StackExchange.Vegetarian           2.964959569  
168.   StackExchange.Ai                   2.917076368  
169.   StackExchange.Devops               2.859960552  
170.   StackExchange.Iot                  2.776448061  
171.   StackExchange.Vi                   2.460942901  
172.   StackExchange.Opensource           2.358354904
```

Comment: So... you mean that, on, say AI, 2.9% of users created their first account on AI? But what does this tell you? My first site was Arqade but I don't spend any time there any more.

Comment: @Catija That most people who use AI probably came from SO As expected most AI users are programmers.  But many more users of Ru discovered it through Google and are not programmers.  But still less than half

Comment: Um... no. This doesn't say what you're interpreting. Just because only 2.9% of users on AI had their first account there doesn't mean that their first account was SO... All it means is that 97.1% of AI users had another account first. All you can use this data for is telling you how good a specific site is at attracting users to the SE network. That's it.

Comment: @Catija If anyone can come up with better data I would love to see it, but ironically the question is also marked as duplicate to the question fromwhere I pulled the data

Comment: ... so edit the question and explain why the duplicate is wrong. That's part of the process! Something being closed as a duplicate when it doesn't answer your question means you need to show us why it's not a good solution for you.

Comment: I started fixing up the formatting, then got bored. 4 spaces do a tab. Pre tags help with keeping it unformatted. I figure someone else can keep adding spaces after the site name if they have enough time and a good reason to