# If a Legendary Badge could be awarded to a user multiple times, how many Legendary badges would Jon Skeet have?

Tags: discussion, community, fun

Recently while browsing MetaStackoverflow, I've encountered a very funny and unusual question:[Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Now I want to know, if a Legendary Badge can be awarded to a user multiple times, how many Legendary Badge does he own?

Comment: If you want to know how many badges of a type he has, why not just [look at his profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges) and find out. It's not a secret.

Comment: Note that all of question is untrue, you see... *hsssss* ***radio line falls to static***

Comment: @JonW, I know that it is *not secret*, but the point of this question is if a Legendary Badge can be awarded to a user multiple times then how many?

Comment: You have just changed the question by editing. However @Richard's answer answers both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## How many legendary badges does Jon Skeet have

[As Oded correctly says the legendary badge can only be awarded once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207845/220332), and so Jon Skeet has exactly 1 legendary badge.

## If you *could* have multiple legendary badges how many would Jon Skeet have

Jon Skeet has been with us for exactly 1880 days. During that time there have only been 15 sad days on which he hasn't got 200+ reputation. These days are

```
May 9th 2010
Aug 10th 2010
Aug 2 2010
Dec 24th 2009
Dec 25th 2009 (still gets 65 on Christmas day 2009, the only Christmas day where Jon Skeet does not get 200+)
Sep 27th 2009
Sept 26th 2009
Jun 13 2009
Jun 13th 2009
May 24th 2009
May 23rd 2009
May 3rd 2009
Apr  11th 2009
October 4th 2008
September 27th 2008
```

Note that after 2009; Christmas day is **not** one of the non 200+ scoring days. (NB Jon Skeet's old answers receive sufficient upvotes that he doesn't have to be physically on Stack Overflow to hit the cap)

As such Jon skeet has 1865 qualifying days which would equate to 12 legendary badges (To put this into context the total number of legendary badges ever awarded is 150)

Comment: This is what I really want to know.=) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

One.

That badge can only be earned once.

It is not hidden information either. If you go to [his profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges) on Stack Overflow, click the badges tab and keep going till you find it. It will tell you how many times a badge has been earned (only if it has been earned more than once).

Comment: The other way to check is this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary?userid=22656)