# Original question being marked as duplicate of a question that should be duplicate

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, duplicate-questions

So here is a question that was asked on SO on Jan 2 '11 at 16:32

[Can we instantiate an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579305/can-we-instantiate-an-abstract-class)

and the other question that was asked on SO on Dec 2 '12 at 16:01

[Interview : Can we instantiate abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670991/interview-can-we-instantiate-abstract-class)

But the first question asked on 2011 is marked as duplicate of the second question which was asked on 2012. My question is why? Is it because the second question is having more views, more votes and a better answer than the first one or it is a honest mistake?

Comment: Did [Jon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9277/151832) posted that question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why?

My question back to you is why not?

There is no specific rule that says older questions cannot be marked as duplicates of newer questions.  It is far less common, but it happens often enough.

And there are no specific rules about which question should be marked as a duplicate of another, so it isn't directly related to the views or votes, although it could indirectly be related.  When it happens, usually it is because the question is framed better, or because the answers provide a better answer.

The whole point to duplicates is to point users to the **best** answers for a specific question, so if the newer question covers the exact same ground, is more clearly worded, and has better answers, why should users be directed to a different question just because it is older?

Answer (score 1):

Question get marked as duplicate not on the basis of date they posted but the more detailed response or popularity of post.

It is allowed to mark an old not famous post to a new post with detailed answers and description.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard rule like new question *must* be closed as a duplicate of the older one. If the new question is written better than the older one, gets better answers, gets more attentions, I don't mind closing older one as a duplicate of the newer one. The criteria of the date should be applied only if both questions have same quality in question and answers.