# Reputation To The Max is not enought against Jon Skeet

Tags: discussion, unicoins, unicorns

I know Reputation To The Max is quite cool and fancy since it is the only way to keep up with [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts), not with every aspect but at least with reputation. But the problem is, well, most of us need a few of those power up to have a chance to keep up Jon. So day of the Unicorn Power should be one of those:

- **Unicorn Up the Skeet**: A power up that will grant you reputation equal to `Jon Skeet's rep + 1`
- **Unicorn Down The Skeet**: A *community* power-up. Instead of powering yourself up, pull Skeet down! Each usage will drop Jon's reputation by 100. Since it in not possible for a single person to drop that damn high reputation down enough, a community work will be needed. So each usage of different user will drop Jon's reputation, so that power stacks up.
- **Disguise like Unicorn**: For a few limited minutes, disguise Skeet! Got his profile picture, his reputation and copy down his profile!
- **Hide the Dull Colored Unicorn**: If overly scored answers of Skeet ruins you day, then just get rid of them. That power up will replace all Jon Skeet answers with a fancy looking-whirling `black hole`, burying the answer to the depths of nothingness.

If you can not find the power-ups in the Unicoin Shop, then Just head to *[Dark Unicoin Black Market](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)*

**Update:** These power-ups have no effect on @Jon Skeet. A Jon Skeet do not need any power-ups to get what had offered above.

Comment: +1 for •Unicorn Down The Skeet I would pay unicorns for that :)

Comment: You know it's Unicoin and it doesn't write unicorn?

Comment: @Rob shhhh... Just silence and do not mention that and you got what you want for the `half price` from the *Dark Unicorn Black Market*

Comment: What would happen if I bought the "Unicorn Up the Skeet" power though?

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet but as [the facts had told](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) there is only one Jon Skeet, and this communitycan not handle a *second Skeet who have beat the un-beatable*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Jon Skeet is not a feature of StackOverflow. If you don't believe Jon Skeet exists, you can ask on Skeptics.SE.

Comment: If @JonSkeet purchased his own powerup it would be as Regius Professor Chronotis explains from Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency: *"You see, the computer that runs it is a rather advanced one.  In fact it is more powerful than the sum total of all the computers on this planet including—and this is the tricky part—including itself."*.