# Why is the post author "unknown" at this particular post?

Tags: support, answers, original-poster

Just came across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9182/179541) and noticed there's **unknown** post author:

[image]

Why is it so? Is it a bug, or another fun fact?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because with multiple contributors to a community wiki, after a certain %age of change, is Jon really the author of the piece?

Sure, he *originated* it, but it changed quite a lot since, so who is it to be attributed to?

We can't tell, hence, unknown.

Comment: So if he would continue with the contribution and did not reach that gap, he would still be author... Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: But 53% comes from the known author. Should %% be removed in case we use "unknown"?