# Why do some community wiki posts say "unknown"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Why do some community wiki posts say that the OP is "unknown", while others actually have a username under "community wiki"?

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263738/8560567) answer has a username on it, while [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/381660) answer just says "unknown".

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Not a duplicate of that. That answer doesn't explain *why* the user is attributed as "unknown", and the answer there directly contradicts the FAQ (lines, not number of edits, are used to determine percentage).

Comment: @Namaste So in the case of the second answer I linked in my question, the reason that it shows "unknown" is because of how much the answer changed since the original?

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog perhaps [this then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256535/why-is-the-post-author-unknown-at-this-particular-post/)?

Comment: Possibly, @Xcoder, but there may have been a shift to designating such posts as "Community <with a mod diamond>" to "unknown".

Comment: Ah, I see, the thing I was seeing that made me think a certain way was actually a red herring. Answer deleted.