# Has SE ever witnessed its posts going viral all over the Internet?

Tags: discussion, statistics, views

First things first: I came across this [viral SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) 3 years ago. It was being shared left, right and center across Facebook groups. I thoroughly enjoyed the post!

Thus my (rather highly curious) question:

Are there any other such posts that had gone viral all over the Internet? What is the reaction of SE moderators/ users in such cases?

P.S: I do realize that this is off-topic, but I'm trying to analyze the trigger behind such posts.And my curiosity has gotten the better of me!

Comment: Just have a go at the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and look for high viewcount on posts and for the tweeted event in the Posthistory http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede I have quickly adapted one of my [queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407757) to give you the high viewcount

Comment: @rene - I did explore SEDE before. Is it possible to search in meta sites too, considering all the fun apparently seems to happen in meta? (at least to me...)

Comment: Yes, the example query I linked you to doesn't rule out the meta sites. They are part of that result set.