# What is the highest score a question can have?

Tags: support, questions, score

What is the highest score a question can have? Hopefully one way or another this will help me find out the answer.

Comment: Here is a query for the [Lowest-scoring questions (not deleted) on SO](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/410666/questions-not-deleted-with-lowest-scores).

Comment: Why don't we vote on this question and find out?

Comment: @angussidney ok, let's break the layout.

Comment: You're not just trying to get a hat here are you?

Comment: @apaul34208 I want to break the meta layout. Also, rep can't go negative right? I only lose 125 rep. Worth it to be able to say my question broke the layout of SE meta =)

Comment: @apaul34208 of course, if I got a hat along the way, I wouldn't complain haha

Comment: ok, I'll help you along then.

Comment: @apaul34208 get 8999 of your friends ^_^

Comment: That's only 4 digits... Actually Meta.SE doesn't have enough users to break the layout. At the moment it looks like there's only 154,878

Comment: long term goals then... @apaul34208 I'm talking about a different hat =P

Comment: I'm surprised my rep is still above 1....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As big as the data type can take](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9138/289845) (look at the second point for the meme) :)

i.e. This is basically infinity. There's no limit to how many up or down votes a question can take.

Comment: I thought so, but wanted to be sure, thanks!

Comment: Why is this answer one of my highest votes? People don't make much sense...

Comment: it answers the question very concisely, and contasins a joke =)

Answer (score 9):

As stated there isn't a bottom limit, but the layout breaks at 10 digits:

[image]

Comment: Now that is cool.