# How can I find the "historically significant" questions?

Tags: discussion, search, locked-questions, historical-lock

Questions that are locked by [historical-lock](/questions/tagged/historical-lock) are very likely to be hilarious<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/607407), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/209994)</sup>. Off course that is [unless someone deletes them first because he doesn't like fun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140376/607407), so he thinks nobody else does.

I wanted to search for these types of questions, but I was not able to figure it out how to filter for this specific type of locked question. Is it possible?

If not, shouldn't we have a tag for those questions that are obviously not serious but also are definitely worth reading?

Comment: Well, ideal solution would be adding some advanced search operator to make the per-site search find them, but that's really unlikely to happen...

Comment: Why do you think so? Searching by close/lock reasons could be useful for other purposes as well...

Comment: Why? Knowing SE for too long, I've seen far more useful ideas/requests ignored for long years. Not telling they won't do it of course, just "highly unlikely", as in "don't hold your breath for this to happen", aka don't get disappointed if it's being ignored. :)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408959/how-to-find-those-old-gems-on-so

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Don't you think the other one is the duplicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the stackexchange.com search, powered by Google. Though some of the provided results are very meta (you can exclude them, but Meta also has historically locked questions, so the results won't be complete).

Just search for [`"the question is off-topic but has historical significance"`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+question+is+off-topic+but+has+historical+significance%22) (with the quotes).

---

It's impossible with per-site search because it's powered by the custom SE search engine, and excludes post notices as they're not being the part of the post body. But the google search has no clue that the notices are something technical, as it just catches any text on the page.

Comment: Now this very question shows up in the results :)

Answer (score 7):

A good result is also using the search [hasnotice:true is:q locked:true](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=4&tab=relevance&q=hasnotice%3Atrue%20is%3Aq%20locked%3Atrue). The historical lock puts a notice on the questions. But the result does also contain other questions with notices of type "Wiki Answer" or others.

Answer (score 6):

The search in the top right - enter [`is:q locked:yes`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+locked%3Ayes) and that will bring up the locked questions. Sorting them by votes is likely what you are wishing to see.

Admittedly, this will bring up *more* than just the historically locked questions (rejected migrations are locked, merges are locked, migrations that haven't been deleted are locked - yes, you can filter those out with [`is:q locked:yes duplicate:no migrated:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+locked%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano) though I'll point out that on Meta.SE that will remove the Jon Skeet Facts as that was migrated from StackOverflow)

Answer (score -1):

I've written a query to get the top 100 posts that have historical significance
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1684103/posts-with-historical-significance

Comment: That query is wrong and showing posts locked for other reasons as well, not only historically locked. That can be nice and useful, but it does not answer this question.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I don't think the query is wrong. A post can be locked for many reasons and only one reason will be displayed (maybe the last one or the one that has higher priority). Ex [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication) is locked by `Historical significance` and `Wiki Answer`. And only the reason `Wiki Answer` is showed

Comment: I just state facts. Going to some of the posts showed in the query, one can clearly see they are not locked for any historical reasons.

Comment: I can modify the query to get posts with `Historical significance` only but I think it is not the correct answer because if a post has many reasons to be locked and `Historical significance`  is one of them, it should be listed