# Unikong game play

Tags: support, april-fools, unikong

There are a few things that I do not understand about unikong.

1. Why is the Unicorn throwing fire at Jon Skeet?

   > [image: play 1]

   I assume the guy is Jon Skeet (because the cover for the game said so), and my understanding is that coins are like reps and unicorns symbolize mods. So why is a mod trying to get rid of Jon by throwing a down button with fire on it?
2. Why is there a troll on top of a unicorn?

   > [image: play 2]

   It's safe to assume the green creature to be a troll, but why is the troll riding the unicorn? Is this an implication that the troll is in control of the moderators?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *are* playing as Jon Skeet: [ordinary guy](http://blog.jonskeet.uk/) and sometime [super hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts). To answer your questions:

1. Not just fire: **flaming downvotes**. Little-known fact: unicorns are very critical. (Clarification: unicorns are *not moderators*.)
2. In order to advance, Jon must zap trolls with **rainbow lasers**. While it does look/sound painful, I believe the effect is not deadly.

Winning the game means Jon has converted both the trolls and unicorns into friends. What adventures they embark on next depends on *your imagination*. (However, I assume the plot is not dissimilar to that of [*Jem and the Holograms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jem_(TV_series)).)

Comment: Wow, wow, Jon skeet wants to make friends with trolls? Flaming downvotes are usually cast by unicorns? Trolls and Jon Skeet end up free riding on the unicorns for reps? Interesting plot ...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'unicorns are very critical'?

Comment: Have you ever met an uncritical unicorn? I haven't.

Comment: [tag:feature-request]: replace "This account is temporarily suspended" by "This account has been zapped with a rainbow laser"

Comment: @randal'thor nope. Accounts zapped with a rainbow beam should be either reformed or turned into stone. Temporarily suspended accounts are banished on the moon.